# Copy symlink AND where it points to using rsync

Tags: symlink, rsync

It doesn't need to be done by `rsync`, but it would be nice not have to write a script to do this, and `rsync` is very close to what I want.

`rsync -a` (or `-l`) can preserve symlinks, and `-L` can dereference symlinks and copy it as if it is normal file/dir. However, is it possible to keep the symlink, and also copy the files/directories the links points to?

Here's an example. Say we have this folder hierarchy:

```
dirA/link_to_file -> ../dirB/file
dirA/link_to_dir -> ../dirC
dirB/file
dirB/not_this_file
dirC/file
dirC/file2
dirD/others
```

and when I do `rsync -aR dirA dest` (or something else), I'd like to have exactly these appear in `dest`:

```
dirA/link_to_file -> ../dirB/file
dirA/link_to_dir -> ../dirC
dirB/file
dirC/file
dirC/file2
```

Is this possible with `rsync`? Thank you.

Let's assume symlinks having absolute path or pointing to outside the source directory can be ignored.

Comment: I think your request is underspecified: you require that
if `dirA/link` is a symlink to `../dirB/file`, then this should be
handled as copying `dirB/file` to `dest/dirB/file` and `dirA/link` to
`dest/dirA/link`.  What if `dirA/link` is a link to
`../../another_file`?  What happens, in general, if `dirA/link`
points to a directory that is higher up in the directory tree?

Comment: Good catch. In my use case, there's no link point to outside the tree, and there's no absolute path in the links.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think no standard utility will do this. In the general case, it might need to create a large number of destinations given a single source, if you have a symlink to a symlink or more generally a symlink whose target contains a symlink (e.g. `a -> b`, `b -> c/foo`, `c -> d/e`: a request to copy `a` should also copy `b`, `c`, `c/foo`, `d`, `d/e` and `d/e/foo`).

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, you are right. Tracking links could lead to including a lot of files, as long as they are still inside the source directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the symlink name and want to transfer the **link** and the **target** you can:

```
rsync -a 'symlink' .
realdir="$(basename "$(readlink -f 'symlink')")"
rsync -a "$realdir" .
```

The first `rsync` transfers just the `symlink`. The second command finds the real directory name, and the second `rsync` transfers the directory content.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible if and only if you these were all in 'mydir' and you were to rsync 'mydir' from one place to another. Rsync isn't capable of copying outside of the path you give it (with the exception of following links). e.g

```
mydir/dirA ...
mydir/dirB ...
...
```

Comment: Yes, this assumption fit my use case. All the links are inside mydir.

Comment: @Wei-Yin then simply tell it not to follow symlinks... or have I misunderstood something

Comment: @xenoterracide: No matter how you invoke rsync, I think it will create a single destination for each source (other than the creation of leading directories). But Wei-Yin wants to create two or more destinations: the link, *and* its target.

Comment: apparently I'm confused...

Comment: @Gilles: there is no need for rsync to follow the symlink, as it will sync the target *anyway*. So it first copies the symlink, making a dangling symlink. Then it goes on to copy everything else in the directory, including the target of the symlink. Voila, everything fits together nicely.

Comment: @Martin: Either I don't understand what you're saying (what options do you propose to pass to rsync anyway? Please write an answer if you think you have a solution!) or you don't understand the requirement: rsync is given a list of symlinks, and it should copy both the symlinks and its target(s) — the targets are *not* listed in the rsync command (so won't be copied with a mere `rsync -a`).

Comment: I indeed did not understand. I would have personally chosen to rsync dirA, dirB, and dirC, and accepted that dirB/not_this_file also gets copied.